# ASP.Net Chart Control with MVC3 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.Net MVC3 and the MS chart controls to draw a pie chart.

It seems I have to set an IMG control with the source set to an action controller.
However this looses the possibility of being able to 'click' on the image and get a redirect to another page with the relevant segment that has been clicked.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial - [here](http://code-inside.de/blog-in/2008/11/27/howto-use-the-new-aspnet-chart-controls-with-aspnet-mvc/). Should help you, however in doing this it will add a viewstate to your views. It basically adds `runat="server"` to your page so treats it like any normal webforms page and violates the MVC principal.

If your bothered about that then there are a number of javascript charts that can be used - the Google chart api is a good start.

Comment: yeah, if it wasn't for your stipulation, I'd have voted this down :)  I agree with the google charts as a good start.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, since the question is about ASP.NET MVC3 and the Razor template language, and the post you linked is from 2008 and uses the ASP.NET template style.